# Bash command to write in temp buffer

Tags: bash

I remember running across this command a while back although I do not remember the command itself. As I remember it, you ran the command, it would create a temp buffer that would then be edited by the default editor (vim) and upon closing the buffer, the command would be executed.

Eg:

```
$ <buffer edit command>
~ # Write bash temp script
~ for i in *; do
~     echo $i
~ done
$ file1
$ file2
$ file3
$ ...
```

Does anyone know what this command is? It is like writing a bash script in vim only without saving the file and just running it.

Comment: Are you thinking of [`fc`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-fc), or was it a standalone command?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want to bind some key combo to `edit-and-execute-command`.  I use:

```
bind '"\C-e": edit-and-execute-command'
```

in my `~/.bashrc`.  When I hit Ctrl-e, it invokes `$EDITOR` and lets me edit the command.  When I save and quit, it executes the edited command.

Comment: Thats it, it was not a command but a shortcut thank you.

Comment: @Drew FYI, the default key combination for this is C-x C-e (that is, hold Ctrl and then first hit x and then e).

Answer (score 6):

If you run `set -o vi` (or have it in your `~/.bashrc`), then pressing <kbd>v</kbd> in normal mode (i.e., press <kbd>Esc</kbd> and then <kbd>v</kbd>) will bring up a buffer as you describe.